# Após muda a URL de login do Wordpress manualmente, fiquei impossibilitado de fazer o logout

Tags: wordpress

Eu criei um novo arquivo PHP no lugar do wp-login.php e renomeie para ser minha nova URL de Login. Funcionou todo ok para logar, agora na hora de fazer o Logout ele me volta a seguinte URL (wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=10c62b8542)
Ou seja, não estou conseguindo fazer o Logout. Será que teria que mudar a função do logout em algum arquivo a mais?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim:

No arquivo **functions.php** do seu tema, adicione esse trecho de código:

```
// Substitui o link de logout pelo retornado na função heathso_logout_link
add_filter( 'logout_url', 'heathso_logout_link' );
function heathso_logout_link() {
    // Retorna o novo link
    return 'https://seusite.com/logout';
}
```

Ok, após adicionar isso, você precisará criar uma página customizada chamada ***"Logout"***.
Pra isso, crie um novo arquivo no seu tema chamado **"page-logout.php"**

Dentro da página **"page-logout.php"** você vai colocar o código abaixo:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Logout */
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
   wp_logout();
   wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit;
} else {
   wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit;
}
?>
```

Logo após adicionar esse arquivo com esse código, vá até a administração do wordpress e crie uma nova página, pode chamar ela de Logout mesmo, na lateral direita você verá uma opção chamada "Modelo", selecione "Logout", salve e seja feliz.

Existem métodos melhores pra fazer isso, adicionando Endpoints customizados ou até mesmo chamando a função na própria página se você enviasse um $_GET['logout'];

Porém, pra facilitar pra você eu fiz dessa maneira :)